# How to find latest rows in my msql using a specific column value

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table called **Access_Status** containing values such as below:

[image]

I would like the table to only return the **Active** users which are Tom Sullivan and John Martin.

It should **NOT** return the Active row for Marta Jenkins since Marta is actually suspended.

What's the best approach for this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and clarify whether you want users who are active, or users who aren't suspended, as these may not be the same thing

Comment: @Strawberry The OP may not be aware but they explicitly state "Active", although they may not mean literally the `"ACTIVE"` value of the field `Àccess`. Then again this question probably seeks answers that broadly answers it as opposed to the very specific values.

Comment: Ideally we're supposed to know the exact table create statement and copyable minimal data as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on the latest row per `name` with a correlated subquery, and ensure that the status is active:

```
select a.*
from access_status a
where 
    t.last_updated_date = (
        select max(a1.last_updated_date) 
        from access_status a1 
        where a1.initial_id = a.initial_id
    )
    and a.access = 'ACTIVE'
```

For performance, you want an index on `(intial_id, last_updated_date)`. Adding `access` as a last column the index *might* also help.

Comment: Like the other solutions, this makes an unnecessary (and in my view , erroneous) assumption about the possible values of status. It's 'suspended' that we care about, not (or at least, not only) 'active'.

Comment: @Strawberry: you don’t know that for sure. Only OP can tell, and they stated: *I would like the table to only return the Active users*.

Comment: @Strawberry I think that you're the one assuming (perhaps from experience) that this is what the OP wants. Whereas the assumption we've made is based on the OP's actual wording, not perhaps an unclear intent.

Answer (score 0):

List of latest rows which are `"ACTIVE"`:

```
SELECT ast1.*
FROM Access_Status ast1
LEFT JOIN Access_Status ast2 ON
  ast1.Initial_ID = ast2.Initial_ID AND ast1.Last_Updated_Date < ast2.Last_Updated_date
WHERE ast2.Initial_ID IS NULL
AND ast1.Access = 'ACTIVE'
-- if the intent is to have latest rows that are NOT 'SUSPENDED'
-- AND ast1.Access <> 'SUSPENDED'
;
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to get ACTIVE users:

```
select A.* from Access_Status A where A.Access = 'ACTIVE' 
and A.Name not in (select Name from Access_Status WHERE Access != 'ACTIVE');
```

Comment: This makes an unnecessary assumption about the possible values of status

Comment: @Strawberry: Given the question description, we can make this assumption. Kadodo14 asked to get only 'ACTIVE' users. 
Although, he/she needs to frame the question clearly with the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your attempts. Actually,  I realize that I did not give enough information. There was an additional column **end_date** which will be null for all active users. So I can use ACCESS='ACTIVE' and end_date is null